# Python. Изменить в последовательности знак *

Tags: python, python-3.x

Если не трудно, то подскажите как это можно реализовать, или изменить мой код  (программа не работает).

> Дано натуральное число n, символы s1, ..., sn. Превратить последовательность s1, ..., sn: если нет символа * , то оставить ее без изменения, иначе заменить каждый символ, встречается после первого вхождения символа * , в знак «-». Пример:
>
> ```
> Вводим:456456     Вывод:456456  
> Вводим:456*456    Вывод:456---
> ```

```
text = input("Введите последовательность: ")

flag = False
new_text = ''
for c in text:
    if c == '*':
        flag = True
        continue

    if flag:
        new_text += '-'
    else:
        new_text += c

print(new_text)
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что ваша программа не работает ?

Comment: @nomnoms12 так 456--- это был как пример ,програма должна делать подобно этому к любому числу,к примеру Ввод 1244789*45,Вывод1244789---

Comment: @nikitahelp Простите, а Вы не можете раскомментировать строку, которую я даже заботливо оставил?) Хорошо, я сделаю это за Вас. Я внёс правку в ответ.

Comment: @nomnoms12 помогло спасибо большое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неэффективно, зато оригинально: https://ideone.com/wmWosG

```
import re
print(re.sub('.(?=.*\*)', '-', input("Введите последовательность: ")[::-1])[::-1])
```

А если звёздочку тоже надо удалять, то так: https://ideone.com/Sd9LcP

```
import re
print(re.sub('\*|.(?=.*\*)', '-', input("Введите последовательность: ")[::-1])[::-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться строковым методом `find` и срезами.

***Пример:***

```py
def main():
    text = input('Введите последовательность: ')

    i = text.find('*')
    text = text[:i] + '-' * (len(text[i:]) - 1)
    print(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Для предыдущего решения, если ввести последовательность без символа "*", тогда - text.find('*') вернет значение "-1" и ответ будет не верным. Я ввел условный оператор.

```
def main():
    text = input('Введите последовательность: ')
    i = text.find('*')
    if i != -1:
        return (text[:i] + '-' * (len(text[i:]) - 1))
    else:
        return text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Пы.сы. я не могу отправить как правку или комментарий )))